# automatic legend translation on chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I cannot find a way to translate the charts legend depending on the html tags language. I have been looking everywhere without success, nothing on chart.js does someone has a clue on how to do that?

this is a page from a webpage made with django and the translation on the page is ran through django i18n package and language switcher button.

I attached an example of a graph on my html page

```
                    var myChart4 = new Chart(ctx4, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                            labels: labels4,
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'Top Sellers (quantity sold/week)',
                                data: defaultData4,
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',


                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',


                                ],
                                borderWidth: 1
                            }],
                            options: {
                                scales: {
                                    yAxes: [{
                                        gridLines: {
                                            drawOnChartArea: false,
                                          ticks: {
                                            beginAtZero: true
                                        }

                                            }
                                    }],
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

"top sellers (quantity sold/week)" is the part that I would like to be able to change. 
and this is what the html page look like:

```
<html>

{%  load static %}
{% load i18n %}


  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Exostock </title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
    <!-- Custom Font Icons CSS-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css3/font.css' %}">

    <!-- Google fonts - Muli-->
{#    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,700' %}">#}
   <!-- theme stylesheet-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css3/style.default.css' %}">

    <!-- Custom stylesheet - for your changes-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css3/custom.css' %}">

{#    <!-- Favicon-->#}
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}">
{#    <!-- Tweaks for older IEs--><!--[if lt IE 9]>#}
{#        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>#}
{#        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->#}
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="search-panel">
          <div class="search-inner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="close-btn">Close <i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
            <form id="searchbox" name="search_res" method="get" action="">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input id="searchbox" type="text" name="search_res" placeholder="What are you searching for...">
                <button type="submit" class="submit">{% trans 'Search' %} </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Navbar Header--><a href="{% url 'Home' %}" class="navbar-brand">
              <div class="brand-text brand-big visible text-uppercase"><strong class="text-primary">Exo</strong><strong>Stock</strong></div>
              <div class="brand-text brand-sm"><strong class="text-primary">X</strong><strong>S</strong></div></a>
            <!-- Sidebar Toggle Btn-->
            <button class="sidebar-toggle"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i></button>
          </div>

              <div class="list-inline-item logout">                   <a id="logout" href="{% url 'logout' %}?next=/loginUser" class="nav-link">{% trans 'Logout' %} <i class="icon-logout"></i></a></div>
          </div>


      </nav>

            <!-- Tasks-->
            <!-- Tasks end-->

            <!-- Megamenu end     -->
            <!-- Languages dropdown    -->
            <!-- Log out               -->

    </header>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <!-- Sidebar Navigation-->
      <nav id="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar Header-->
        <div class="sidebar-header d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="title">
            <h1 class="h5">{% trans 'Inventory Analytics' %}</h1>
            <p>{%  trans 'Welcome' %}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Sidebar Navidation Menus--><span class="heading">{% trans 'Main' %}</span>
           <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'Home' %}"> <i class="icon-home"></i>{% trans 'Home' %} </a></li>
                <li ><a href="analytics.html"> <i class="icon-chart"></i>{% trans 'Analytics' %} </a></li>
                <li><a href="items.html"> <i class="icon-chart"></i>{% trans 'Items' %}</a></li>
                <li><a href="Supplier.html"> <i class="icon-chart"></i>{% trans 'Supplier' %}</a></li>
                <li><a href="SupplierData.html"> <i class="icon-padnote"></i>{% trans 'Grouped Replenishment' %}</a></li>
                <li><a href="ItemData.html"> <i class="icon-padnote"></i>{% trans 'Individual Replenishment' %}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- Sidebar Navigation end-->
      <div class="page-content">
        <div class="page-header">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <h2 class="h5 no-margin-bottom">{% trans 'DASHBOARD' %}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <section class="no-padding-top no-padding-bottom">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="statistic-block block">
                  <div class="progress-details d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between">
                    <div class="title">
                      <div class="icon"><i class="icon-paper-and-pencil"></i></div><strong>{% trans 'Items in Alert' %}</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="number dashtext-1">
                        <h1>
                         <p> <a href="detailstockalerte.html">{{ count_alerte_items }}</a></p>
                    </h1>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="statistic-block block">
                  <div class="progress-details d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between">
                    <div class="title">
                      <div class="icon"><i class="icon-paper-and-pencil"></i></div><strong>{% trans 'ITEMS TRENDING' %}</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="number dashtext-2">
                          <h1>
                             <p><a href="detailstocktrend.html">{{ count_trend }}</a></p>
                          </h1>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="statistic-block block">
                  <div class="progress-details d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between">
                    <div class="title">
                      <div class="icon"><i class="icon-paper-and-pencil"></i></div><strong>{% trans 'Alerte Service Level' %}</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="number dashtext-2">
                        <h1>
                           <p><a href="detailalerteservice.html">{{ count_alerte_service }}</a></p>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="statistic-block block">
                  <div class="progress-details d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between">
                    <div class="title">
                      <div class="icon"><i class="icon-paper-and-pencil"></i></div><strong>{% trans 'Candidates Replenishment' %}</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="number dashtext-4">
                          <h1>
                             <p><a href="detailscandidate.html">{{ count_candidates }}</a></p>
                           </h1>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="no-padding-bottom">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="card-footer small text-muted"> {% trans 'TWO WEEKS INVENTORY MOVEMENT' %}</div>
                <div class="line-chart block">
                  <canvas id="myChart5"></canvas>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="card-footer small text-muted">{% trans '90 DAYS INVENTORY DEMAND PREDICTIONS' %} </div>
                <div class="doughnut-chart block">
                  <canvas id="myChart6"></canvas>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="no-padding-bottom">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="stats-2-block block d-flex">
                  <div class="stats-2 d-flex">
                    <div class="stats-2-content"><strong class="d-block">
                        <h3> {{ total_inventory_val }} </h3>
                    </strong><span class="d-block">{% trans 'Inventory Value in dollars ($)' %}</span>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="stats-2 d-flex">
                    <div class="stats-2-content"><strong class="d-block">
                        <h3>{{ count_orders }} </h3>
                    </strong><span class="d-block">{% trans 'Orders Placed' %}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="stats-2-block block d-flex">
                   <div class="stats-2 d-flex">
                    <div class="stats-2-content"><strong class="d-block">
                        <h3>{{ items_actifs }} </h3>
                    </strong><span class="d-block">{% trans 'quantity of active items' %}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                   <div class="stats-2 d-flex">

                    <div class="stats-2-content"><strong class="d-block">
                        <h3>{{ suppliers_actifs }} </h3>
                    </strong><span class="d-block">{% trans 'Quantity of active suppliers' %}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            </section>
           <section class="no-padding-bottom">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="card-footer small text-muted">{% trans 'TOP PERFORMERS' %}</div>
                <div class="line-chart block">
                  <canvas id="myChart4" height="175"></canvas>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="card-footer small text-muted">{% trans 'ITEMS IN DIFFICULTY' %}</div>
                <div class="bar-chart block">
                  <canvas id="myChart3" height="175"></canvas>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer__block block no-margin-bottom">
          <div class="container-fluid text-center">
          <div class ="row text-center">

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <form id= "form_{{ language.code }}" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="text" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
                                <select name="language" id="">
                                    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                                    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                                    {% for language in languages %}
                                        <option value="{{ language.code }}" {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected {% endif %}>
                                        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                                        </option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                            <button type="submit" value="Go" class="learn_more2">Go</button>
                            </form>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <p class="no-margin-bottom  align-items-center" >2020 &copy; Exostock.<a></a></p>
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-3">
               <a href=""><span>Support</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
               <a href=""><span>Documentation</span></a>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include the html code?

Comment: for sure, just updated my post

Answer (score 1):

Chart.js's settings are very flexible. Instead of a static text labels like,

```
...
labels: 'Top Sellers (quantity sold/week)',
...
```

You can use a function like

```
...
labels: i18nLabels("eng"),
...
```

And then of course you need to create that function that will extract the language from the `<html>` tag or from the browser settings.

Here is a demo: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/rNOEBmY?editors=0010, try switching from `labels: i18nLabels("spa")` to `labels: i18nLabels("eng")` around line 19.

Comment: thank you for your input, being a beginner in javascript, I am struggling big time. I have an idea tho, would it be possible to include a if statement in the chart.js label like: if text in div tag == "english text", then label == "english label", else label =="french label". I feel like it would be easier especially with only 4 sentences, but not sure if that works?

Comment: @Peyo, yes, take a look at this new codepen: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/GRpVJZP, it will take the language from the `lang` attribute in the `<div>`, it doesn't need to be a `<div>`, it can be the `<html>` too.